# How to have a link on local pc to an application on a remote pc?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, networking

I have a WPF application on a server on my network with his app.config file and all the stuff it needs to run; I would like to open this application on clint pc on the network, but executing it on the server: I am trying to have a link to the application with some sort of network path, but I can't manage to do it.

I'll explain it in a second way: something like desktop links to programs in theri folders, but instead of being in the same machine, the program would be on a remote server in the network... is that possible somehow?

Comment: Do you actually need to run the program on the server or do you just want to run the program locally but not have to copy it locally before you run it? If you want the program to run locally without downloading please edit your question to explain what is going wrong when you try to do it, be sure to include any error logs.

Comment: Also, if you really do want to just run it on the server and have it look like it is running locally this is not on topic for this site, you should ask on SuperUser.com or ServerFault.com.

Comment: Yes I need to run in on the server and have it look like it is running locally, in this way I don't need to download it on the clients. Thank you for the suggestion of more appropriate websites btw!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Terminal Server technology "[RemoteApp](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755055.aspx)" should act like you are wanting it to act. The app will appear to be running on the client machine but it actually will be running on the server.

You will need the server running the app to be Windows Server 2008 R2 or newer and it will need to be configured as a terminal server roll.

Comment: I'll use this solution, should be perfect, thank you!